# What Algo to use to classify my data to 3 classes

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I'm looking for a way to differentiate between 3 classes(classification problem) for each OBJECT to classify.

I have a large dataset(millions of lines). There are 2 features, each have 100 values(scaled to 0-1).

Each line refers to one sample of a specific Object(Object_id, 100 columns of my first feature, 100 of my second feature).

Each object(that has to be classified to either 3 classes) have at least 100 samples(1 sample is 1 line)

Unfortunately Classe 3 counts only 1/10 compared to 1 and 2(each object of classe 3 have around 500 samples, however classe 1 and 2 objects have around 2000 and more).

In order to do the classification, I need to take a bach of samples for each object(for exmaple 20, 50, or 100).

I dont know what algo suites better for my case, I'm new to deep learning so bear with me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break this down to two main questions: how to handle unbalanced datasets and which model to use.

### Unbalanced datasets

Most machine learning algorithms are sensitive to some degree on unbalanced datasets. This is a huge challenge for Machine Learning in fields like medical diagnostics or seismology, where you have 98% "normal" readings and 2% "event" readings. **There is no silver bullet to this problem**. Some algorithms are more resilient to an unbalanced dataset, and some that deliberately unbalance their datasets to encourage a strong model (see *bagging*), and there are options to augment your data by introducing cloned data with statistical noise. However, your easiest and most effective approach is to decimate your dataset to make it balanced.

You have a class split of 2000|2000|500 datapoints. Randomly sample 500 datapoints from each of the first two classes so you have a balanced 500|500|500 dataset. It is important to randomly sample, instead of simply taking the first 500 as you want a representative sample of the class population. see the `numpy.random` module for how to select your datapoints.

### Model selection

Although Deep Learning is portrayed as the be-all and end-all for machine learning, it represents a significant amount of time and cost to prepare, train and monitor. A typical approach to any new problem is to try some "baseline" shallow learning models. Often you'll see the following scenarios:

1. Your baseline models fail to train.
2. Your baseline model trains and fits moderately
3. Your baseline model trains and fits closely

In the first scenario, your deep learning model is unlikely to train either. In the third scenario there is no need to build a deep learning model when a simpler algorithm can solve it. Scenario 2 is your candidate fro deep learning.

So what models could you use?

Well, we know that it's a supervised problem, that we have a good number of samples, and that we are looking to classify. Your best bet for this kind of question is a *Random Forests* model. There is a good simple implementation in `scikit-learn` and hundreds of tutorials.

Alternatively, if you're looking at class fit through clustering, *K-means ++* models (and co), or even *Gaussian Mixture Models* are a good place to start (again, see scikit learn's `sklearn.clustering` and `sklearn.mixture`)

If it fits *well*, then your work is done. If it fits *moderately*, think about deep learning. If it fails to fit, get add more features (and more diverse features) to your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your response